# How to select all the xml elements by excluding specific xml element using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I am new in xml.I have the following xml:

```
<root>
 <parent1>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <child2>2</child2>      
 </parent1> 
 <parent1>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <child2>2</child2>      
 </parent1>
 <parent1>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <child>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <child2>2</child2>   
  </child>      
 </parent1>
 <child2>2</child2> 
 </root>
```

I want to exclude all the `<child2>` regardless of their position inside xml file and produce the following output:

```
<root>
 <parent1>
  <child1>1</child1>    
 </parent1> 
 <parent1>
  <child1>1</child1>  
 </parent1>
 <parent1>
  <child1>1</child1>
  <child>
  <child1>1</child1>   
  </child>      
 </parent1> 
 </root>
```

i did this xpath but it does not return every thing else:
`/root/parent1/*[not(self::child2)]`
what xpath expression is need to do so?please help.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Such output can't be produced using pure XPath.

Note that according to [the XPath 1.0 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), *"the primary purpose of XPath is to address parts of an XML document"*. And in XML, `root` element i.e opening tag, content, and closing tag is considered one unit. There is no such `root` element that doesn't contain `child2` element in your XML that XPath can address. XPath 1.0 has a *very limited* capability to return something that isn't in the original XML.

You'll need to rebuild `root` element according to your need, or copy the original XML document and remove all `child2` elements to get the wanted result. This can be done using XSLT, XQuery, or a general-purpose programming language of your choice.

---

In case you just want to get all elements, anywhere in the XML document, excluding `child2`, then you can use this XPath : `//*[not(self::child2)]`. The result will be *individual elements* though, not structured as one XML document as you seems to expect, judging from the output XML posted.